# When user clicks on teaser title, I want new browser window to open

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I know that if I add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag this will cause a new window to open when the link is clicked.
But how do I add this to the `<a>` tag the Drupal way ?
This is a teaser title, not an anchor that I created in a block or have direct edit ability to.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marius says you can use the node template file, but that involves non-compliant markup. If you use JS, then the Drupal way uses behaviors. Also you shouldn't assume `$` is `jQuery` in D7. Here's an example:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.titleTargetModify = {
    attach: function(context) {
      $('h2 a:not(.titletarget-processed)', context)
      .addClass('titletarget-processed')
      .attr('target', '_blank');
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

[More details](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `target="_blank"` using jquery, so you avoid using a non compliant tag.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.teaser-title-class').attr({
        target: "_blank", 
        title: "Opens in a new window"
    });
});
```

Change **teaser-title-class** with your teaser title class. You can find what class it is using "inspect element" in chrome or firefox. If teaser class isn't available, you can use selector in other ways, e.g.: `$('#teaser a')`

Answer (score 1):

this can be changed in your theme file (usually is node.tpl.php ) and you just add the target attribute there. keep in mind that the target attribute is not xhtml compliant and you should use javascript to add the target attribute